# Non-activerecord models structure in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My attempt looks like this, non-activerecord model with inheritance.
`app/models/matching_method.rb`:

```
class MatchingMethod
  attr_accessor :name
end

class LD < MatchingMethod
end

class Soundex < MatchingMethod
end
```

By this I can benefit from using `MatchingMethod.descendants`.
This works quite well. So I tried to move each class into its own folder.

```
models/
  - concern/
  + matching_method/
    - ld.rb
    - soundex.rb
  - matching_method.rb
```

And for each class:

```
class MatchingMethod::LD < MatchingMethod
end
```

However, this time `MatchingMethod.descendants` couldn't find
inherited classes anymore.

Any suggestions? Or should I redesign this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails loads `ld.rb` only when you request `MatchingMethod::LD`. It resolves the class through `const_missing`. You need to request `MatchingMethod::LD` in code or require the file `matching_method/ld.rb` manually. Until the class file is loaded, `MatchingMethod` doesn't know anything about it's descendant `LD`:

```
MatchingMethod.descendants
# => [] 

MatchingMethod::LD        
# => MatchingMethod::LD 

MatchingMethod.descendants
# => [MatchingMethod::LD]
```

To load all classes from `matching_method` dir:

```
Dir['app/models/matching_method/*.rb'].each do |f| 
   require Pathname.new(f).realpath
end
```

To reload them again without restarting the application (like the Rails loader in development environment):

```
Dir['app/models/matching_method/*.rb'].each do |f| 
   load Pathname.new(f).realpath
end
```

**It won't monitor file changes.** You need to `load` the file manually after saving changes. And it won't remove any existing methods/variables. It will only add new or change existing ones.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to load these descendant methods automatically?

Comment: @PhatWangrungarun yes, Dir['app/models/matching_method/*.rb'].each {|f| 
   require Pathname.new(f).realpath}

Comment: This works great, thanks! However every time I make some changes in descendant classes I need to restart the app in order to get changes. Is this normal?

Comment: Good question. You definitely want to re-invent the Rails :) Change `require` to `load` and repeat it after every change. `Require` loads the file only once. `Load` is the same, but reloads it again and again. Nobody use `load` iIn production environments because of performance impact.